# How to pass code to asymptote from the command line?

Tags: windows, asymptote

I would like to pass some code into Asymptote from the Windows command line.  I see in the Asymptote manual the command line option:

```
-u, -user string        General purpose user string
```

I assumed this is what I should use so I created a DOS command as follows:

```
asy asyfile -u "int i = 5"
```

Then my asyfile.asy file contains `write(i);` resulting in an error `no matching variable 'i'`.  Does anyone know if this is the intended use of the `-user` option?  Is there another command-line option that would do what I need?  Thanks!

Comment: In Linux you can use a pipe with the `-` option for Asymptote to read from stdin, like `echo 'int i=5; include "asyfile.asy";'|asy -`. This probably works in Windows as well (but I didn't test that).

Comment: @Marijn:  Thanks for your comment!  It inspired me to read further.  While I'm sure your solution would work, I have discovered how to properly use the `-u` option as shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend defining `i` before usersetting():

```
int i;
usersetting();
write(i);
```

That way the user can enter either `asy asyfile -u i=5` or `asy asyfile` on the command line.

Comment: Great idea, thanks!  Also thank you for your work on Asymptote.  It's my favorite programming language for smallish tasks.  I only switch to C++ for more complex things.  And a lot of my C++ projects create asymptote code to visualize their results.

Answer (score 2):

Marijn's comment inspired me to read the remainder of the Command-Line Options section in the manual.  I discovered that I was misusing the `-u` option.  I needed to add a `usersetting();` command to my asyfile.asy file.

So `asy asyfile -u "int i = 5"` works as expected if my asyfile.asy file contains the following:

```
usersetting();
write(i);
```